# How to unmarshall both 0 and false as bool from JSON

Tags: json, go

Currently am mapping the output of a service that, lets say, liberally interchanges 0 and false (and 1 and true) for its boolean types. Is there a way to use a more permissive parser for the built in encoding/json unmarshal function? I've tried adding ,string to the json tags to no avail.

An example of what I'd want:

```
type MyType struct {
    AsBoolean bool `json:"field1"`
    AlsoBoolean bool `json:"field2"`
}
```

then, given input json:

```
{
    "field1" : true,
    "field2" : 1
}
```

the resulting struct would be:

```
obj := MyType{}
json_err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input_json), &obj)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj.AsBoolean) //"true"
fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj.AlsoBoolean) //"true"
```

Comment: I doesn't matter that the service/software itself is liberal about 0/false and 1/true, if it outputs JSON with "1"s for values it knows are boolean, then it is producing malformed JSON. Boolean and Number are different types in JOSN, and it a marshaller doesn't correctly deal with that, it has no right to expect the de-marshaller to.

Comment: i mean, i agree that the output is bad, this isn't a vacuum though and i really have to process this output and have no control over fixing it

Comment: You can implement the UnMarshalJson method for your type, not sure what you want the end result to be. In your example, the boolean and int have different field names, like they are different things. I don't think viewing it as the "API interchanging the types" is correct. If it was always the same field name, then that might be the case. Either way, you could always use the clean simple, fail proof method of having different types and on your end and trying to unmarshal into them one by one until you get a success. The paradigm is often used for responses that could have data or error.

Comment: I guess the example is misleading, there are times when the same field is 0 or false

Comment: Ah, figured as much. I just threw in an edit. I would do the custom UnmarshalJSON method and read the json for int, bool and string and then just set the bool on my type. For anything else I'd error or default to false. I could provide an answer but there are probably quite a few examples you can find and I'm about to leave work.

Comment: fyi this seems like a decent blog on the topic; http://attilaolah.eu/2013/11/29/json-decoding-in-go/  only complaint is that he chooses different paradigms on either end... Like one case he implements Decode for his type, the on the other end he does MarshalJSON. Personally I say be consistent there but whatever.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you Will Charzuck for the answer, however, it did not work for me unless I used a pointer method receiver, and set the value of the pointer in the function body.

```
type ConvertibleBoolean bool

func (bit *ConvertibleBoolean) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    asString := string(data)
    if asString == "1" || asString == "true" {
        *bit = true
    } else if asString == "0" || asString == "false" {
        *bit = false
    } else {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Boolean unmarshal error: invalid input %s", asString))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: worked fine. just changed asString to replace "\""   asString := strings.Replace(strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(string(data))), "\"", "", -1)

Comment: This is the fixed version of the answer below. It looks simple and useful.

Answer (score 12):

Ended up using a special "boolean" type, and where I was using a normal bool, swapped for this:

```
type ConvertibleBoolean bool

func (bit ConvertibleBoolean) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    asString := string(data)
    if asString == "1" || asString == "true" {
        bit = true
    } else if asString == "0" || asString == "false" {
        bit = false
    } else {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Boolean unmarshal error: invalid input %s", asString))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Small tip: Go style convention is to use `mixedCaps` (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps) variable names, so `as_string` should be `asString` (or just `s` if it's a small function).

Comment: Also another small tip: there is a method [`fmt.Errorf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) so you don't need `errors.New()` and `fmt.Sprintf()`. (Btw `fmt.Error()` does exactly the same under the hood.)

Comment: This did not work, I think we need a pointer to ConvertibleBoolean. See answer below

Comment: you might want to take a look at [`strconv.ParseBool`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseBool)

Answer (score 6):

This is my take on it. In case you need something to deal with a few extra cases. Add more as needed.

```
// so you know what's needed.
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

// NumBool provides a container and unmarshalling for fields that may be
// boolean or numbrs in the WebUI API.
type NumBool struct {
    Val bool
    Num float64
}

// UnmarshalJSON parses fields that may be numbers or booleans.
func (f *NumBool) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    switch str := strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(string(b), `"`)); str {
    case "true":
        f.Val = true
    case "false":
        f.Val = false
    default:
        f.Num, err = strconv.ParseFloat(str, 64)
        if f.Num > 0 {
            f.Val = true
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

See it in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sXMvQY5dJ9f).

I've also been known to something like this:

```
// FlexBool provides a container and unmarshalling for fields that may be
// boolean or strings in the Unifi API.
type FlexBool struct {
    Val bool
    Txt string
}

// UnmarshalJSON method converts armed/disarmed, yes/no, active/inactive or 0/1 to true/false.
// Really it converts ready, ok, up, t, armed, yes, active, enabled, 1, true to true. Anything else is false.
func (f *FlexBool) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if f.Txt = strings.Trim(string(b), `"`); f.Txt == "" {
        f.Txt = "false"
    }
    f.Val = f.Txt == "1" || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "true") || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "yes") ||
        strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "t") || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "armed") || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "active") ||
        strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "enabled") || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "ready") || strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "up") ||
        strings.EqualFold(f.Txt, "ok")
    return nil
}
```

And if you want to go real small:

```
// Bool allows 0/1 and "0"/"1" and "true"/"false" (strings) to also become boolean.
type Bool bool

func (bit *Bool) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // txt := string(b) // original, no strings.
    txt := string(bytes.Trim(b, `"`))
    *bit = Bool(txt == "1" || txt == "true")
    return nil
}
```

See this one in [playground: bool/int/string](https://go.dev/play/p/_Cl9mUkLngC).
The old version: [playground: bool/int](https://play.golang.org/p/57s4xwGo3pw).

Answer (score 0):

For [@Twitch Captian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5879880/twitch-captain) 3rd example, I found the result of `string(b)` caused `txt` to equal `""1""` instead of `"1"` as I expected. To remedy this I unmarshaled the byte array into `txt`, then evaluated the contents for `"1" || "true"`

```
// Bool allows 0/1 to also become boolean.
type Bool bool

func (bit *Bool) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var txt string
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &txt)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *bit = Bool(txt == "1" || txt == "true")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Good catch! In my other examples I had a `strings.Trim()` to solve that problem. And in hindsight, `bytes.Trim()` is probably faster.