# Unmarshal only gives me first element of array that is nested in JSON response

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling, flickr

I am trying to work with the Flickr API and I have an endpoint which gives me a response like this

```
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 500,
    "perpage": 1,
    "total": 500,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "12345",
        "owner": "12345@N01",
        "secret": "12ab345xyz",
        "server": "1234",
        "farm": 1,
        "title": "Some Title",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
     ...
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

I have a struct that looks like this

```
type FlickrResp struct {
    Photos struct {
        Page int            `json:"page"`       //what page the results were retreived from
        Pages int           `json:"pages"`      //total number of pages of results
        Perpage int         `json:"perpage"`    //number of results per page
        Total int           `json:"total"`      //total number of results
        Photo []struct {
            ID string       `json:"id"`         //image ID
            Owner string    `json:"owner"`      //owner ID
            Secret string   `json:"secret"`     //owner secret
            Server string   `json:"server"`     //server ID
            Farm int        `json:"farm"`       //farm ID
            Title string    `json:"title"`      //image title
            Ispublic string `json:"ispublic"`   //is image publicly viewable?
            Isfriend string `json:"isfriend"`   //is image owner my friend?
            Isfamily string `json:"isfamily"`   //is image owner my family?
        }                   `json:"photo"`      //array of objects with details of photos
    }                       `json:"photos"`     //object that holds information about photoset
    Stat string             `json:"stat"`       //status
}
```

and I'm trying to Unmarshal thusly

```
var fr FlickrResp                                               //create blank struct of type FlickrResp to hold JSON
resp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(flickrCB.Body)                      //read HTTP GET response
if err != nil {

}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), &fr)                               //serialize JSON into template
```

flickCB.Body comes from an http.Get

The problem is that I'm only getting the first element of the photo array. I can see that I have more than one element when I print the response object cast as a string. What am I doing wrong? I've been banging my head against Unmarshal and more complicated JSON responses for a few days now.

Comment: Are you reading the error from `json.Unmarshal`? When I try the above I get a problem with the type mismatch between `ispublic`, `isfriend`, and `isfamily` versus the strings the struct is expecting. If I change the types it seems to work alright. Here's an example with the change, including usage for one field of `json.Number`, which can be handy in cases like this - https://play.golang.org/p/4fE_MkxgxS. I see two entries in `Photo` in the results.

Comment: That did it, thank you. I don't want to talk about how many times I went over this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered originally in comments, but for a bit more clarification:

There was an uncaught error from `json.Unmarshal`:

`json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string`

Caused by a type mismatch between the flicker API giving `ispublic`, `isfriend`, and `isfamily` as integers, but the struct was expecting strings. An easy fix is just to convert them to ints.

Another option for these sorts of situations is to use [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number), which wraps a basic string from the source json and provides a few convenience methods to convert it to a number later (or just keep it as a string). By doing say

```
Ispublic json.Number `json:"ispublic"`   //is image publicly viewable?
Isfriend json.Number `json:"isfriend"`   //is image owner my friend?
Isfamily json.Number `json:"isfamily"`
```

It will work fine, and the result can easily be gotten as a string via `fr.Ispublic.String()`.

A more elaborate change that might be useful in this situation is to use a custom boolean type. The values in question seem to mirror booleans, but integers do not map cleanly to booleans either. A custom deserialized type can be used. Borrowing from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856454/golang-how-to-unmarshall-both-0-and-false-as-bool-from-json) elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
type ConvertibleBoolean bool

func (bit ConvertibleBoolean) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    asString := string(data)
    if asString == "1" || asString == "true" {
        bit = true
    } else if asString == "0" || asString == "false" {
        bit = false
    } else {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Boolean unmarshal error: invalid input %s", asString))
    }
    return nil
}
```

The above would let you declare the `Is*` values as `ConvertibleBoolean`, and will automatically map the 0 & 1 values you'd presumably get in those fields from Flickr to booleans.