# How do you rewrite types in struct?

Tags: json, go

Source that I can't change:

```json
{
    "perfectly_normal": "bar"
    "fooBool": "0"
}
```

What's on the table:

```golang
type hwo struct {
    normality  string `json:"perfectly_normal"`
    makeMeBool ?????? `json:"fooBool"`
}

json.Unmarshal(body, hwo)
```

What's a good way to turn `"0"`/`"1"` to `false`/`true`?

Comment: Create your own type and write json marshal/unmarshal functions for it. That is: `type stringyBool bool`, so that `stringyBool` gets marshaled/unmarshaled from 0/1 string values, but is otherwise bool.

Comment: See question [How to unmarshall both 0 and false as bool from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30856454/5728991) for implementations of torek's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and a method to convert the passed `DTO` in to the desired `struct`.

Below is some pseudo code where the `DTO` is used to create a new `hwo` struct based on the values in the `DTO`.

This gives the added benefit of being able to mutate any data from the DTO, in the instances where you have more than just a `int` to `boolean` conversion.

`marshal` and `unmarshal` functions for a custom type as mentioned in the comments are also a good shout and probably simpler.

```
type hwo struct {
    normality  string  `json:"perfectly_normal"`
    makeMeBool boolean `json:"fooBool"`
}

type DTO struct {
  normality string
  fooBool   int
}

func ToHwo(dto DTO) hwo {
  fooBool := true
  if dto.fooBool == 0 {
    fooBool = false
  }

  return hwo {
    normality: dto.nornality,
    fooBool: fooBool,
  }
}
```